# GCP slack tutorial 'slash command'; failed to deploy google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, slack

When going through the [tutorial for creating a basic slack app with google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/slack), the deployment stage fails with:

> >gcloud functions deploy kg_search --runtime python37 --trigger-http
>   Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: 'API_KEY'

Trying to figure out how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 29 the code `os.environ['API_KEY']` is trying to fetch the API_KEY from shell environment variables but as it's undefined the program crashes.
As you discovered, when you get rid of the first part of the `or` statement the exception is not raised anymore.

The way to set environment variables when you deploy Google Cloud Functions is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#using_environment_variables).

Could you retry the deployment step running `gcloud functions deploy kg_search --set-env-vars API_KEY=YOUR-API-KEY --runtime python37 --trigger-http` and see if it works that way?

Comment: Thanks!
I managed to fix it, but I just also wanted to make sure google's tutorial worked out of the box, so either by specifying the steps you're hinting at or by removing the code that raises the exception.

Comment: The team in charge is now aware of the issue. thank you for reporting this!

Comment: Thanks :) Could you accept the answer to close this question as solved if everything is alright?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I went back to the `main.py` file, and found the following in line 29:
`developerKey=os.environ['API_KEY'] or config['KG_API_KEY'])`. I switched it to `developerKey=config['KG_API_KEY'])`

If anyone knows how to avoid the error message and rely on the `or` statement to pull the API_KEY from the config, please comment here and for extra point make and send a PR to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/slack/main.py) file.